# Apollo 3: deleting nested item from cache

Tags: reactjs, caching, apollo

I have an object type `entity` that can be related to another object type `something` through a list `entityInstances`. The `something` is also a in a list within `somethingContainer`:

```
query somethingContainer {
  id
  somethings {
    id
    entityInstances {
      id
      entity {
        id
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `entity`s can appear in several `entityInstance`s, but the instances are unique to their `something`s, and so are the `something`s to their containers.

The issue comes when deleting an `entity`. Then each of the queries that contain the entity (nested within the 3 layers) need to be updated, but it's not obvious which queries that would be.

I've looked into using `cache.modify` but I can't see how to use it without knowing the id's of the relevant `entityInstance`s (or those of the relevant `something`s).

Before I've used a little soft delete hack where I use `writeFragment` to set the `id` of the relevant `entity` to `null`, and filtering out these in components. But this never felt like a good solution, and it's even worse with the upgrade to Apollo 3 (we log an error whenever a query or mutation has no `id`, which after the upgrade also logs at `writeFragment`).

Another option is to do something like rerunning all `somethingContainer` queries but that can get expensive.

Any ideas?